NSOutlineView and hierarchical lines
ALL,
In Windows when you display a tree control, you can have a vertical lines running from the root down, like in a tree branches.
However, I just checked the NSOutlineView documentation here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsoutlineview and I didn't see a possibility of having such lines to be displayed.
Is it not possible?
I can make a screenshot on Windows from the Explorer to make it more clear...

As far as I know, NSOutlineView does not draw such lines.

@ willeke, thx for confirmation.

You can try to draw them yourself by customizing the cell view knowing the cell level in the tree, but there is no built-in functionality for this.
